# AWS Api Gateway - Lambda Function Client Certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, client-certificates, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

We have created a client certificate in our API Gateway. When using proxy, the certificate is being sent correctly to the end-point.

However, when using lambda we can not access and/or resend/forward the certificate for https requests using the https package ( require('https'); ).

How can we use the API Gateway Client Certificate in our lambda function?

Comment: Did you get to know how to validate the api gateway generated cert in Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway only sends the client certificate to HTTP integrations. Not to Lambda functions as that communication is already secured by AWS credentials/roles.